# Testing Cross Browser Extension With Jest, How To Mock Chrome Storage API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

After putting off testing for a while now due to Cypress not allowing visiting `chrome://` urls, I decided to finally understand how to unit/integration test my extension - TabMerger. This comes after the many times that I had to manually test the ever growing functionality and in some cases forgot to check a thing or two. Having automated testing will certainly speed up the process and help me be more at peace when adding new functionality.

To do this, I chose Jest since my extension was made with React (CRA). I also used React Testing Library (`@testing-library/react`) to render all React components for testing.

As I recently made TabMerger open source, the full testing script can be found [here](https://github.com/lbragile/TabMerger/blob/master/__tests__/Tab.spec.js)

Here is the test case that I want to focus on for this question:

```
import React from "react";
import { render, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";

import * as TabFunc from "../src/Tab/Tab_functions";

import Tab from "../src/Tab/Tab";

var init_groups = {
  "group-0": {
    color: "#d6ffe0",
    created: "11/12/2020 @ 22:13:24",
    tabs: [
      {
        title:
          "Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careersaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
        url: "https://stackoverflow.com/",
      },
      {
        title: "lichess.org • Free Online Chess",
        url: "https://lichess.org/",
      },
      {
        title: "Chess.com - Play Chess Online - Free Games",
        url: "https://www.chess.com/",
      },
    ],
    title: "Chess",
  },
  "group-1": {
    color: "#c7eeff",
    created: "11/12/2020 @ 22:15:11",
    tabs: [
      {
        title: "Twitch",
        url: "https://www.twitch.tv/",
      },
      {
        title: "reddit: the front page of the internet",
        url: "https://www.reddit.com/",
      },
    ],
    title: "Social",
  },
};

describe("removeTab", () => {
  it("correctly adjusts groups and counts when a tab is removed", () => {
    var tabs = init_groups["group-0"].tabs;
    const { container } = render(<Tab init_tabs={tabs} />);
    expect(container.getElementsByClassName("draggable").length).toEqual(3);

    var removeTabSpy = jest.spyOn(TabFunc, "removeTab");

    fireEvent.click(container.querySelector(".close-tab"));
    expect(removeTabSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(container.getElementsByClassName("draggable").length).toEqual(2); // fails (does not remove the tab for some reason)
  });
});
```

I mocked the Chrome API according to my needs, but feel that something is missing. To mock the Chrome API I followed this post (along with many others, even for other test runners like Jasmine): [testing chrome.storage.local.set with jest](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48894790/4298115).

Even though the Chrome storage API is mocked, I think the issue lies in this function which gets called upon initial render. That is, I think the `chrome.storage.local.get` is not actually being executed, but am not sure why.

```
// ./src/Tab/Tab_functions.js
/**
 * Sets the initial tabs based on Chrome's local storage upon initial render.
 * If Chrome's local storage is empty, this is set to an empty array.
 * @param {function} setTabs For re-rendering the group's tabs
 * @param {string} id Used to get the correct group tabs
 */
export function setInitTabs(setTabs, id) {
  chrome.storage.local.get("groups", (local) => {
    var groups = local.groups;
    setTabs((groups && groups[id] && groups[id].tabs) || []);
  });
}
```

The reason I think the mocked Chrome storage API is not working properly is because when I manually set it in my tests, the number of tabs does not increase from 0. Which forced me to pass a prop (`props.init_tabs`) to my `Tab` component for testing purposes (https://github.com/lbragile/TabMerger/blob/f78a2694786d11e8270454521f92e679d182b577/src/Tab/Tab.js#L33-L35) - something I want to avoid if possible via setting local storage.

Can someone point me in the right direction? I would like to avoid using libraries like `jest-chrome` since they abstract too much and make it harder for me to understand what is going on in my tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I have a solution for this now, so I will share with others.

I made proper mocks for my chrome storage API to use localStorage:

```
// __mocks__/chromeMock.js
...
storage: {
    local: {
      ...,
      get: function (key, cb) {
        const item = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
        cb({ [key]: item });
      },
      ...,
      set: function (obj, cb) {
        const key = Object.keys(obj)[0];
        localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(obj[key]));
        cb();
      },
    },
    ...
},
...
```

Also, to simulate the tab settings on initial render, I have a `beforeEach` hook which sets my `localStorage` using the above mock:

```
// __tests__/Tab.spec.js
var init_ls_entry, init_tabs, mockSet;

beforeEach(() => {
  chrome.storage.local.set({ groups: init_groups }, () => {});
  init_ls_entry = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("groups"));
  init_tabs = init_ls_entry["group-0"].tabs;
  mockSet = jest.fn(); // mock for setState hooks
});
```

**AND** most importantly, when I `render(<Tab/>)`, I noticed that I wasn't supplying the `id` prop which caused nothing to render (in terms of tabs from `localStorage`), so now I have this:

```
// __tests__/Tab.spec.js
describe("removeTab", () => {
  it("correctly adjusts storage when a tab is removed", async () => {
    const { container } = render(
      <Tab id="group-0" setTabTotal={mockSet} setGroups={mockSet} />
    );

    var removeTabSpy = jest.spyOn(TabFunc, "removeTab");
    var chromeSetSpy = jest.spyOn(chrome.storage.local, "set");

    fireEvent.click(container.querySelector(".close-tab"));

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(chromeSetSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    chrome.storage.local.get("groups", (local) => {
      expect(init_tabs.length).toEqual(3);
      expect(local.groups["group-0"].tabs.length).toEqual(2);
      expect(removeTabSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });

    expect.assertions(4);
  });
});
```

Which **passes**!!

[image: current testing state]

Now on to drag and drop testing